# Stopping potential and EM radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, photoelectric-effect

I'm a little confused about something

We know from the photoelectric effect, that when a beam of light falls on the surface of a metal with very low ionization energy, electrons get ejected, one way to measure the kinetic energy of these electrons is by decelerating them with a parallel electric field till they stop, and according to what I see in books conservation of energy implies that kinetic energy of electrons should be equal to the work done on them by this external electric field, but, we all know that whenever a charge accelerates or decelerates it emits EM radiation right? why is the latter always not taken into consideration when applying conservation of energy??

Comment: The amount of emitted radiation is way too small to matter. Maybe somebody will give you a quantitative answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering!